# iPhone device ownership statistics

Tags: ios

Is there a website to check iPhone and iPad device ownership similar to the way we can check iOS's version ownership like this website:

https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Thanks...

Comment: Can you explain again what you're asking for?  iPhone and iPad are both ios devices and so are already included in the link you provided.

Comment: iOS is the operating system. I'm talking about the actual devices. How many people use the iPhone 4s as opposed to the iPhone 6s. I am an iOS developer and it would be helpful to know how many people are using which device because of the different screen sizes.

Comment: Apple does not release similar rolled up statistics either as sales figures or active user figures. Are you looking for that yes/no answer or are you open to third party estimates? If the latter, you might explain what you found and why it's not applicable. For example - a game developer in the freemium market might have vastly different usage patterns than a pro app developer like AutoCad use base would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent data I've been able to find is for iPhones from 2015 and it's from Localytics.  The company states they...

> ...examined over 100 million iPhone devices. The data for this study
>   represents iPhones that had active app sessions logged during August
>   2015.

Here's the hightlights of the study, the details can be found here.
[image]

Here's some info from [Unity3D](http://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/device-ios.html) based on their usage for March, 2016.  It inlcudes all Apple devices.

```
Top on 2016-03:

iPhone 5S: 21.0%
iPhone 6: 13.5%
iPad Mini: 9.5%
iPhone 6S: 6.7%
iPhone 5: 5.6%
iPhone 6 Plus: 5.5%
iPad Air: 5.2%
iPad Mini 2: 4.6%
iPhone 4S: 4.4%
iPad 2: 3.6%
iPad Air 2: 3.2%
iPad 4: 3.1%
iPhone 6S Plus: 2.9%
iPhone 4: 2.7%
iPhone 5C: 2.6%
iPad 3: 1.8%
iPod Touch 5th: 1.3%
iPod Touch 6th: 0.9%
iPad Mini 3: 0.8%
iPad Mini 4: 0.7%
iPad Pro: 0.2%
Apple TV 4: 0.0%
iPod Touch 3rd: 0.0%
```

As a developer, I just use AutoLayout and not worry about what device my users have.  That seems to work for me but each app is different.